# Should a Mongoose controller be a class or an object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, controllers

I've seen it defined a few different ways:

(1) Methods on a class: https://github.com/volodymyrrudyi/generic-express-mongoose-controller-example/blob/master/resources/controllers/base.js

(2) Static methods on a class (don't have an example here but it also seems to make sense to me)

(3) Plain methods (possibly attached to an object, although this example just exports them directly): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes

...but I'm not really sure if there are certain use cases/contexts to use one or the other. Is there a standard usage here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Class or Object for it, but I always use Class, which is good.

In NodeJs or ES6, we have Class. It is powerful.

With the design pattern MVC in NodeJS and Express, You can use:

1. Routes: call controller
2. Controller: extents more Controller (if you need) and use Model
3. Model: it will doing with data. But I suggest you create some service, and include Service in Model, connect DB in Model and use DB in Service
4. View: In controller, render view :)

Do you have any question?

Feel free to comment, I'm happy to help